# Referring to NodeChildren in groovy code

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy

I am in Eclipse 3.6.2 and using maven (0.12) and groovy (2.7) plugins. I have the following code:

```
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren;
...
protected Container getContainerFor( NodeChildren containerNode) {
...
```

The issue is that Eclipse is happy with all this, but doing a maven install fails *for some developers but not others*.  The issue for those is that it appears to fail since NodeChildren's declaration is not *public*:

```
class NodeChildren extends GPathResult {
...
public NodeChildren(final GPathResult parent, final Map<String, String> namespaceTagHints) {
...
```

even though methods within the class are public.

Has anyone experienced this behavior?  It's strange since it works for some and if those deploy all is well... I don't find examples that deal with NodeChild(ren), though I did find this:

[Maven dependency for groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChildren](http://mavenhub.com/c/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChildren)

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Comment: [NodeChildren was made public as of 2013-03-28](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6070?focusedCommentId=322848&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-322848)

Comment: Thanks Tim!  What version of Groovy was that?

Comment: Bah, just checked and it's [not in 2.1.3](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_2_1_3/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChildren.java) (the latest release). I'm guessing it will be in the 2.2 branch :-/

Comment: Thanks again - so is there a way to use it now?  And why does it sometimes work, sometimes not?

Comment: No idea why it sometimes works, sometimes not... There must be some difference between dev machines, but I'm at a loss to explain what :-/ Not sure of a way to make it public now either. What error do you get? Is this in Groovy code?  Is there a way to utilise dynamic typing to skip typing the containerNode for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was to change the Groovy compiler used by Maven to the same one used by Eclipse.

Thanks for the inputs.  Hope this helps someone else.